# Proving that $(1+10^n)$cannot be a prime number when $(n>2)$

Tags: prime-numbers

Proving that $$(1+10^n)$$ cannot  be a prime number

when $n>2$

Comment: Is this known?  Easy if $n$ is odd.  Computer found none beyond 101...searched pretty far.

Comment: If $n$ is odd, proving divisibility by $11$ is a doddle. For even $n>2$, I can't see a way right now. Testing reveals that the numbers are divisible by one of $17,29,73,101$ and then the numbers become too large for the online calculator I'm using. I can't see a clear pattern here.

Comment: For $n-$odd it can be factored. Also if $n=l\cdot 2^k, k>0,l>1$ it can be factored. But when $n=2^k,k>0$ it seems to be prime.

Comment: Fairly clear that $n$ has to be a power of $2$, but I can't rule those out.

Comment: @Svetoslav $353|10^{16}+1$

Comment: @GudsonChou I have checked it for limited values of $n$.

Comment: This might have an amazingly simple solution that none of us have thought of yet (doh!) but since it's already generated quite a lot of discussion, I'm upvoting it - not often do we get such simple questions that are not so simple to crack.

Comment: I've checked it fairly deep (8 digits).  But I see no way to attack $n=2^k$.

Comment: @lulu you are right. So we only have to  exclude this case somehow.

Comment: @Svetoslav No, it's not this one case.  $19841|10^{32}+1$ and $1265011073|10^{64}+1$.

Comment: @lulu I mean the case $n=2^k,k>0$

Comment: Oh, sorry.  Agreed.  But I've looked over the factors and can see no pattern (which doesn't mean there isn't one).  $257|10^{128}+1$ so maybe there's a Fermat prime angle that works at least sometimes.

Comment: I think that a pruned down version of this (with the "obvious" cases excluded) is a ripe candidate for Math Overflow - but then again, I think it's now quite certain this is an open problem, so it might not be well-received.

Comment: A prove that there are no primes $10^n+1$ with $n>2$ is probably out of reach. And it will also be very difficult to find such a prime, if it exists (See my answer below)

Comment: @Deepak the problem is actually open and probably remains open until someone finds such a prime.It is hard to imgaine that it can be proven that there is no such prime.

Comment: For the fermat numbers, the situation is similar. $65,537$ is the largest known Fermat prime, and the numbers $2^{2^k}+1$ with $5\le k \le 32$ are composite. The smallest fermat number with unknown character is $2^{2^{33}}+1$. Most mathematicians believe that there are only finite many fermat numbers, some believe that are none besides the known, but some mathematicians believe that there infinite many.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The number $$10^n+1$$ can only be prime if $n$ is of the form $2^k$.

A simple proof of this fact

Suppose, $n$ has an odd prime factor $p$. Denote $q:=\frac{n}{p}$
Then $10^q+1$ is a non-trivial factor of $10^n+1=10^{qp}+1=(10^q)^p+1$
because for every number $t$ dividing $10^q+1$, we get $10^n+1=(10^q)^p+1\equiv (-1)^p+1\equiv 0\ (\ mod\ t\ )$

The generalized fermat numbers have been studied deeply. The smallest
number $10^n+1$, for which it is NOT known if it is composite or prime,
is

$$10^{2^{24}}+1$$

The numbers $10^{2^k}+1$ with $2\le k\le 23$ are composite.

So, a prime of the form $10^n+1$ with $n>2$ would have at least a magnitude comparable
to the largest known prime. It would have at least $2^{24}+1=16,777,217$ digits!

See here :

http://www.prothsearch.net/GFN10.html

for more informations

Comment: "The number $10^n+1$ can only be prime if $n$ is of the form $2^k$."

Could you elaborate a bit more on this, please ?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying ! +1